# Hudson | Ant - Mail target | [mail] Failed to initialise MIME mail: javax/mail/MessagingException

Tags: java, email, ant, hudson

I am trying to send a mail from a ant target and it works from command line. But the same doesn't work from Hudson UI.

The exception is same as [Failed to initialise MIME mail: javax/mail/MessagingException while running Ant Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315113/failed-to-initialise-mime-mail-javax-mail-messagingexception-while-running-ant) , but in my case it doesn't work only from Hudson.

Target:

```
<target name="test_mail">
<mail from="xxx" tolist="yyy" subject="Test Mail" encoding="mime" messagemimetype="text/html"/>
</target>
```

Does anyone have any idea about the issue ?

Thanks,
Gayathri

Comment: Do you have jars like : mail.jar , activation.jar , ant-javamail.jar in ant's lib directory ?. It worked for me once I added them to build/lib on my project. Related link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639172/ant-mail-task-issue-in-sending-mail-with-attachments

Comment: yes. classpath is correct, as it works from command line.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "ant-javamail" lib.